# .htaccess 301 redirect with trailing ? in URL

Tags: redirect

any assistance on this redirect question is appreciated. I am adding several redirects from an old url to new pages on a website. Several of the old urls that are indexed have a trailing ? in the url. www.example.com/products/1234?

I have the following redirect in place that does not work

Redirect 301 /products/1234? http://www.example.com/test/

If I remove the question mark above the redirect does work, however it then adds in a question mark to the url it's redirecting to. http://www.example.com/test/?

How do I get this to redirect without it displaying a ? in the URL?